# Div not looping correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, css

I'm trying to get my code to display multiple divs. But seems to only display one div correctly.

```
<?php
// database connection
//$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE field5='Cohen'");
echo " <div id='1'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class='tutorName'>" . $row['field1'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorPrice'>" . $row['field2'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorInstitution'>" . $row['field3'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorLocale'>" . $row['field4'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorPhone'>" . $row['field5'] . "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want the following to loop and over using the fields above (field1, feild2, etc):

```
<div id='' name='' class="column threecol">
<div class="course-preview premium-course">
<div class="course-image">
<a href="listing.php"><img src="img.png" /></a>
<div class="course-price">
<div class="corner-wrap">
<div class="corner"></div>
<div class="corner-background"></div>
</div>
<div class="price-text"><span class="amount">PerHour</span></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="course-meta">
<header class="course-header">
<h5 class="nomargin">TutorName </h5>
<div class='gender'>Gender: </div>
<div class='price-range'>Price Range: </div>
<div class='institute'> Institute: </div>
</header>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are multiple rows with `field5=Cohen`? The code itself should work

Comment: What's the generated HTML?

Comment: How are the other div's not displaying correctly? As a side, is you query actually `... WHERE field5='Cohen'`, and `$row['field5']` is `class='tutorPhone'`?

Comment: Make sure that "field1-5" are valid named fields inside your table.

Answer (score 0):

Is your $result line really commented out in the real code? Or did you just add that comment for the example? If it's commented-out in the code you're testing, then that's probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you want this? , 1 div wrap all content like table tr

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo " <div id='{$i}'>";
echo "<div class='tutorName'>" . $row['field1'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorPrice'>" . $row['field2'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorInstitution'>" . $row['field3'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorLocale'>" . $row['field4'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class='tutorPhone'>" . $row['field5'] . "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
  $i++;
}
```